# Jenkins Trigger Isn't working in pipeline

Tags: triggers, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have to schedule a pipeline to trigger a particular time in future , I can't mention an year in cron of build periodically so I have to add the triggers inside my pipeline:

```
triggers {
    when { LocalDate.now()== "2020-08-17" }
    cron('35 11 17 8 1')
}
```

But this doesn't trigger the pipeline.  However , with the build periodically I get pipeline triggered but there I have no way of mentioning the year. I want pipeline to be triggered just once on a dedicated date and time. Also , I am not allowed to trigger it remotely.Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain what you're trying is not possible, at least not within the pipeline syntax. `LocalDate.now()` can only be run when the pipeline is *already* running, whereas the `cron` command schedules the build with Jenkins directly.

What you could do is triggering the pipeline periodically (for example, on every August 20) and checking the year as the first step, stopping the run if it's not the correct year. You could also use a secondary pipeline with that sole purpose to prevent your main pipeline having an aborted run in its history.